# Entity framework update failed and throws exception of adding MS_Description Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried to update a object using the following code:

```
 using (var context = new ApplicationEntities())
 {
   var entry = context.Entry(obj);
   entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But,it fails most of the time by throwing the following exception.

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details. System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An
>   error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for
>   details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Property cannot be
>   added. Property 'MS_Description' already exists for 'ForeignKeyName'.
>       The statement has been terminated.

Here, `ForeignKeyName` is the name of foreign key relationship with other table.

My question why it is trying to add `MS_Description` property for the `ForeignKeyName`.

I also tried update only selective properties of the object except the foreign key. But, it also fails and throws the similar exception. The situation happens in production environment and okay in local development environment.

**Update:**

I found the main problem. Its neither related to entity framework nor it's related to application. I have found that updating a row of this particular table fires a trigger. The definition of the trigger is quite erroneous and it tried to add MS_Description for the foreign key name. I removed the particular statement and it works now.

Comment: Check whether `MS_Description` has foreign key relationship

Comment: 'MS_Description' is extended property of the table and it's not column of the table

Comment: please check with the database whether that column exists.

Answer (score 0):

Although not EF, a possible alternative might be to use [Drapper](https://github.com) (an abstraction layer for Dapper).

With Drapper you'd supply the SQL statement to update the record(s) giving you full control of the execution.

Your update method might look something like

```
public Model Update(Model model)
{
    return _commander.Execute(model) ? model : null;
}
```

Where `_commander` is an instance of Drapper's `IDbCommander`. That's half the code you'd write for EF with much, much more control.

You should check it out.